# Hamming distance for grouped results

Tags: stata, levenshtein-distance, hamming-distance

I'm working with a data set that contains 40 different participants, with each 30 observations.
As I am observing search behavior, I want to calculate the search distance for each subject per round (from 1 to30).

In order to compare my data with current literature, I need to use the Hamming distance to describe search distances.

The variable is called `Inputs` and is a string variable with binary inputs 0 or 1 with a length of 10. E.g: 
Input Type 1 Subject 1 Round 1: 0000011111
Input Type 1 Subject 1 Round 2: 0000011110

Using the Levensthein distance, my approach was simple:

```
sort type_num Subject round_num
gen input_prev=Input[_n-1]
replace input_prev="0000000000" if round_num==1 //default starting position with 0000000000 to get search distance for first input in round 1

//Levensthein distance & clearing data (Levensthein instead of hamming distance)
ustrdist Input input_prev
rename strdist input_change
```

I am now struggling with getting the right Stata commands for the Hamming distance. Can someone help?

Comment: You should show the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? As I understand it, Hamming distance is the count of characters (bits) that differ at corresponding positions of strings of equal length. So, given two variables and wanting comparisons within each observation, it is just a loop over the characters.

```
clear
set obs 10
set seed 2803 

* sandbox 
quietly forval j = 1/2 {
    gen test`j' = ""
    forval k = 1/10 {
        replace test`j' = test`j' + strofreal(runiform() > (`j' * 0.3))
    }
}

set obs 12 
replace test1 = 10 * "1" in 11 
replace test2 = test1 in 11
replace test1 = test1[11] in 12 
replace test2 = 10 * "0" in 12 

* calculation
gen wanted = 0
quietly forval k = 1/10 {
    replace wanted = wanted + (substr(test1, `k', 1) != substr(test2, `k', 1))
}

list 

     +----------------------------------+
     |      test1        test2   wanted |
     |----------------------------------|
  1. | 1110001111   1001101000        7 |
  2. | 1111011011   1101011111        2 |
  3. | 1011001111   1110110111        5 |
  4. | 0000111011   1011010100        8 |
  5. | 1011011011   1111100110        6 |
     |----------------------------------|
  6. | 0011111100   0100011110        5 |
  7. | 0011011011   0011111010        2 |
  8. | 1010100011   1011000100        5 |
  9. | 1110011011   1010010100        5 |
 10. | 1001011111   0100111001        6 |
     |----------------------------------|
 11. | 1111111111   1111111111        0 |
 12. | 1111111111   0000000000       10 |
     +----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! the formula is actually working and giving me the distance output I was looking for. Can you tell me whether this calculation is "Hamming" conform?

Further, I was trying to use the stata command `sdhamming´. I do not understand how to use the commands in order to get outputs. I am just receiving an error message
hamming Input-input_prev, subsmat(scost) pwdist(dist)
Normalising distances with respect to length
       hammingdistance():  3200  conformability error
               hamming():     -  function returned error
                 <istmt>:     -  function returned error

Comment: I have never used that command: you are asked to explain the provenance of community-commands. I don’t understand your first question,

Comment: I am trying to understand, whether the command that you have shared above can be named as the "Hamming Distance" when describing the method in an academic paper?

Comment: If it’s what you want, you just need a definition in the literature that is supportive, or else a different name. If you want something a little or a lot different, say what that is.

Comment: alright thanks. Just want to make sure that what you've shared can be used as the hamming distance. Otherwise, I'd need to use the official sdhamming function provided by STATA with which I am struggling

Comment: That is not official — which in Stata means bundled with what the company provides — and a command, not a function. Sorry, but working out whether and how it relates to your structure is too much of an ask for me. Why not contact the program author?

Comment: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6772729 gives the eponymous reference, although  sum of absolute difference as a measure of similarity is older yet.